# Laravel 4 - Duplicate Url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am having a problem with the confide package for user authentification.

My problem is that when I login, I am redirected to the login page which throws an notFoundHttpException because the url I am redirected to is duplicated... looks like this:

```
http://www.mypage.dev/http://www.mypage.dev
```

My virtual host is set up like this here

```
https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs/blob/master/apache.conf
```

What is making this happen?

---EDIT---

Gathering more experience...

It seems that this occurs when the following redirect is used:

```
return Redirect::action('Controller@action')
```

If I use:

```
return Redirect::to('/action')
```

everything is just fine.

My route look like this:

```
Route::get('/action', 'Controller@action');
```

Comment: How are you performing the redirect? Please show some of the relevant code.

Comment: Actually I didn't implement the redirect myself but am using the confide package (https://github.com/Zizaco/confide). I have seen this happen with Laravel 3 too, though.

I am running laravel 4 on a Debian VM ( virtual box ) with its own virtualhost

Otherwise followed the standard laravel 4 setup proceedure.

Comment: This just came up again in a different spot. I am starting to see a pattern. This time it occurs when I redirect to an action return Redirect::action('Controller@create', array('types' => $types))->withErrors($errors); it sends me to /http://www.mypage.dev/create which the browser turns into http://www.mypage.dev/http://www.mypage.dev/create

Comment: did you fix it? Please share your findings.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It hasn't been a blocker yet, so I haven't put much effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Route` to

```
Route::get('action', 'Controller@action');
```

Your current route's definition appends `/action` to the end of the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the underscore, the url `http://newsletters_app.dev` is invalid according to `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`. Because of this, `HTML::link()` is generating a duplicate base. Solution is to simply remove the underscore from the URL.